# Sort array by values in subarrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array like this:

```
let pairs = [[2,"test"], [7,"buzz"], [3,"asd"]]
```

How can i sort the outer array by the first values? (descending)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a compare function to [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) that examines the first element in each array, to determine the required order.

```
> let pairs = [[2,"test"], [7,"buzz"], [3,"asd"]]
> pairs.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]);
[ [ 2, 'test' ], [ 3, 'asd' ], [ 7, 'buzz' ] ]
```